# Can't pay $5 to register as a Web Store Developer, because the button is missing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome Version: Version 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit)
OS: Windows 10
Extensions: None enabled

I want to upload an extension to the web store developer dashboard. Since it will be my first one I have to pay 5 dollars as an entry fee. When I tried the first time I was able to see a button to press that loaded the form in which I put my CC info.

But I had trouble with my cc and I had to try it again later. But now the button is missing from the page and there is nothing I can do to bring it back.

This is a picture that shows a screen shot with the button enabled and what I'm seeing right now.
[Link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoEVv.jpg).

Does anyone here had a similar problem and knows how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

It is known bug and being tracked at [crbug.com/652178](http://crbug.com/652178)

I doubt whether Google Webstore team have fixed it yet, but as a workaround you can try updating your payment details at https://wallet.google.com , then retry.  I got it solved earlier in same steps.

Hope it helps!